# Black margin beneath the app bar

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I'm adding support for 16:9 screens for my app, and I'm having an issue with the 1080p resolution. I just updated Visual Studio to the Update 2, and I noticed that when I try to run the app in the 1080p emulator, I get a thin black bar beneath the appBar, and I have no idea why.

This is the code I use to create the app bar, and it works fine both WVGA, WXGA and 720p screens.

```
        //App bar
        ApplicationBar = new ApplicationBar();
        ApplicationBar.Mode = ApplicationBarMode.Minimized;

        //Pulsanti nell'app bar
        ApplicationBarIconButton appBarButton = new ApplicationBarIconButton(new Uri("/Assets/AppBar/favs.png", UriKind.Relative));
        appBarButton.Text = Personal_Food_Trainer.Resources.AppResources.InfoButton;
        appBarButton.Click += new EventHandler(navigaCrediti);
        ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(appBarButton);

        //Vota app
        appBarButton = new ApplicationBarIconButton(new Uri("/Assets/AppBar/like.png", UriKind.Relative));
        appBarButton.Text = Personal_Food_Trainer.Resources.AppResources.VotaButton;
        appBarButton.Click += new EventHandler(vota);
        ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(appBarButton);

        //Guida
        appBarButton = new ApplicationBarIconButton(new Uri("/Assets/AppBar/questionmark.png", UriKind.Relative));
        appBarButton.Text = Personal_Food_Trainer.Resources.AppResources.guidaButton;
        appBarButton.Click += new EventHandler(navigaGuida);
        ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(appBarButton);
```

I attached a screenshot, so that you can see the problem I'm having:

[image: This is a screenshot, so that you can see the problem]

Is there something wrong with my code, or does the appBar in WP8.1 require something I'm missing? Thank you for your help! :)

Also, I'm using the appBar just with 16:9 screens by adding this code:

```
if (App.Current.Host.Content.ScaleFactor != 150)
        {
            return;
        }

        //App bar...
```

How can I distinguish between a 1080p screen and a 720p screen by using the ScaleFactor?
The appBar works fine with 720p screens, so I just want to run the fix with 1080p screens

Comment: I am not seeing the problem - can you post a second screenshot how it should look like?

Comment: If you look closer at the bottom of the bar, you can see that there is a black bar like 5pixels tall, between the app bar and the border of the screen. This is a screenshot where it isn't there: http://i.imgur.com/gg1gcsE.png

Comment: did you tried your app on real device? there is a small chance that this behavour only on emulator

Comment: No, I don't have a 1080p Windows Phone :/
But if I open another app in the emulator, the games hub for example, the app bar is displayed correctly...
This is the link for the app, would you mind trying it with your WP (I assume you have one with a 1080 screen) and tell me if there is this problem? Thanks!
http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/store/app/personal-food-trainer/5910296b-6126-43b6-80c5-0aae14193a1e

Comment: @Sergio0694 the `ScaleFactor` should work. Take a look at this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/jj206974(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Extend size of main parent grid view which contains your background. drag it down because if you don't then It may not look good on 6" inch devices like Lumia 1520 or Lumia 1320

Comment: My main canvas covers the whole screen, I don't understand why I have this problem. Also, this only happens with 1080p screens, the layout works fine with 720p screens instead. 
Shouldn't the 1080p layout be an upscaled version of the 720? The aspect ratio is the same :/
What can I do? Thanks for your help!

Comment: I also face same prob with my Lumia 1320 and Lumia 1520 becuse its HD display with resolution of 720x1280 another have WVGA or QVGA display ther is no prob. with that i just simply make my grid bigger then phone, and prob solved with HD display. I make my grid size's hight around 1290 and width around 730 and inner grid are used with same as screen resolution like 720 and 1280.